# Difference between memcpy and copy by assignment

Tags: c++, c, memcpy

```
Struct A
{
   uint16_t len;
   uint8_t  cnt;
   uint8_t  unit;
   uint32_t seq; 
};
```

This struct A is serialized into a `char *` buf. If I want to deserialize the individual values eg:

```
uint16_t len = 0;
memcpy(&len, buf, sizeof(len));
```

or I can just do

```
uint16_t len = (uint16_t) buf;
```

Which one is better or are both the same?

Also to deserialize the whole struct, if I just do

```
A tmp;

memcpy(&tmp, buf, sizeof(A));
```

Would this work fine or should I be worried about padding etc from the compiler?

Comment: You probably meant `len = *(uint16_t*)buf`. Well, that's a strict aliasing rule violation.

Comment: What's a strict aliasing rule violation?

Comment: This is another question, which is actually already answered multiple times. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Comment: is the C++ tag relevant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the data is copied into `char[]` buffer, it may not be properly aligned in memory for access as multi-byte types. Copying the data back into `struct` restores proper alignment.

> If I want to deserialize the individual values eg:
>
> ```
> uint16_t len = 0;
> memcpy(&len, buf, sizeof(len));
> ```

Assuming that you have copied the `struct` into `buf`, this is perfectly valid, because the language guarantees that the initial member would be aligned with the beginning of the structure. However, casting `buf` to `uint16_t*` is invalid, because the buffer many not be properly aligned in memory to be addressed as `uint16_t`.

Note that getting elements of the struct other than the initial one require computing proper offset:

```
uint32_t seq;
memcpy(&seq, buf+offsetof(struct A, seq), sizeof(seq));
```

> Also to deserialize the whole struct, if I just do
>
> ```
> A tmp;
> memcpy(&tmp, buf, sizeof(A));
> ```
>
> Would this work fine or should I be worried about padding etc from the compiler?

This would work fine. Any padding embedded in the `struct` when you copied it into the `buf` would come back into `tmp`, along with the actual data.

Comment: Sorry I meant `len = *(uint16_t*)buf` .

Comment: @EternalLearner Yes, I assumed that you meant to cast to pointer and dereference, that's why I wrote about casting `buf` to `uint16_t*` pointer.

Comment: so would there be a difference between memcopy and doing this assignment copy? If yes, what would that be? Which method is preferred?

Comment: @EternalLearner: This post describes the differences, ergo yes there are differences. This post also describes why one works and why the other doesn't, so presumably the one that works is preferred.

Comment: Also, assuming I did not pad this struct (if I get this over the network) would the above method be safe?

Comment: @EternalLearner If you get the `struct` over the network, the method would be unsafe, unless the sender uses compatible hardware. If it does not, you would need to work out some protocol with `ntoh`/`hton`.

Comment: @EternalLearner ideally, you develop a formal *protocol* for transmitting the data serially (over network, or otherwise), then comply with that protocol with both the sender and the receive. Doing so has the added advantage, if you set up the protocol wisely, of being platform-independent; something which struct-dumping into a buffer, sending, then buffer-dumping into a struct, is sorely lacking.